# Jooq generates POJO missing comments

Tags: java, sql, jooq

eg.

SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `collect` (
  `travel_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'travel id',
  `description` varchar(64)  COMMENT 'description',
  `creat_time` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'creat time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`travel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='collect';
```

The resulting POJO is as follows.

```
/**
 * collect
 */
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.9.2"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class Collect implements Serializable {

    private Integer       travelId; 
    private String        description;
    private LocalDateTime creatTime;

    ...
}
```

The POJO I want should be like this.

eg:

```
private Integer       travelId //trave_lId
```

or

```
/* trave_lId */
private Integer       travelId
```

my code generator:

```
.withPojos(true)
.withDaos(true)
.withSpringAnnotations(true)
.withJavaTimeTypes(true)
```

the POJO field does not have a corresponding comment.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (as of jOOQ 3.9 and 3.10), comments are only generated on tables and records, not on POJOs. That's a missing feature which should be implemented in a future jOOQ version. I've created a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6456

You can override the `JavaGenerator` class from jooq-codegen in order to generate those comments manually, e.g. by overriding `JavaGenerator.generatePojo()`.